# python-minimal dependency jam in LTS upgrade from lucid to precise

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade

Relatively far along in the LTS upgrade with a call to "apt-get distupgrade" there appeared:

```
E: could not perform immediate configuration on python-minimal
```

I tried installing python2.7-minimal.  This generates the message:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7-minimal:
 python2.7-minimal depends on python-minimal (>= 2.6.6-3+squeeze1); however:
  Version of python-minimal on system is 2.6.5-0ubuntu1.
dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
```

No doubt this is one of the challenges presented by the concept of an LTS upgrade.  Is it safe to use force to replace python2.6-minimal with python2.7-minimal, and, if so, will it take care of the first error?

Any clues?